# Lot of cracking noises in the attic

Tags: attic, structural, noise

I bought a house about a year ago and ever since there has been a ton of cracking noises coming from the attic. They sound like thermal expansion noises, but they happen all day and night, in any weather or temperature. I notice them the most in the master bedroom. When it happens, it's never just 1 pop, it's 3-4 back to back and they appear like they're in line, like the noise is moving across the ceiling. It happens several times a day, sometimes within the same hour. There are no cracks in the drywall that would indicate structural problems, but this is my first house so I'm not exactly sure what to look for. Is this something I should get checked out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could simply be thermal expansion and contraction, delayed due to the large heat capacity of a home. It takes quite a while for the solar gain that has soaked into an attic to be released, for example.

I'd stake out your attic Columbo-style and give it a good listen and feel. Chances are it's not a sign of structural problems, but it's surely an annoyance.